# Wordpress Feed Error

Tags: rss, feed, xml

When you access mysite's feed you get the error message shown below. I've checked my `functions.php` file that no have any extra space on bottom end of file.

> error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start
>   of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first
>   error.

Comment: Please add debugging [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Disable all of your plugins and see it that helps. Switch to a default theme and see if that help.

Comment: i've installed wp cache plugin after asking question i've deleted plugin and its work fine....

but how i can keep both, wp cache plugin and feed functionality.

Comment: Closed as it in fact is a plugin support question.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds similar to a problem I had with my RSS feed

just as @s_ha_dum suggests it could be theme or plugin related:

a) is it a theme related problem? --> switch to the default theme 2012 to check.
if yes: You should also check if you have empty lines in between your code in functions.php:

```
 ?>

 <?php
```

or if there are some direct echos. In my case it was an empty line at the bottom of functions.php after `?>`, so I now don't use `?>`to close `<?php`  at the end of the functions.php.

b) is it a plugin related problem? --> deactivate your plugins to check since some plugins can output empty lines.
if yes: then activate your plugins, one by one to find the problematic plugin.

ps:

To debug my RSS feed I like to use

http://feedvalidator.org

and remember to remove feed caching if you have one.

Comment: i've installed wp cache plugin after asking question i've deleted plugin and its work fine....

but now how can i keep both, wp cache plugin and feed functionality.

Comment: I have used wp-super-cache, w3tc and hypercache without any RSS problems.

Comment: Hi, noticed you have unaccepted the answer few months later, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: because i won't found solution of my problem in this answer sorry...

Answer (score -3):

http://cameron.ghost.io/fixing-rss-feed-in-wordpress/

follow the instructions here from the theme directory.  This issue is caused by whitespace somewhere in your php files.  There is a single terminal command to fix.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As you see I'm new to Stack Exchange. Will remedy in my next answer